keyboard shortcut to split a quarto code block in VS Code
I have scoured the internet before posting such a basic question, but have found no solution. In RStudio I can split one code chunk into two chunks by typing cmd + opt + i on mac while cursor is within an existing code chunk. Is there no equivalent functionality in VS Code?
If I type the keyboard shortcut to create a VS Code block (shift + cmd + i) while cursor is within an existing code block it merely creates a new code block below.
I want this:
1 + 1
<imagine my cursor here>
1 + 1

to become this:
1 + 1

1 + 1


What do you mean by "code chunk"? What language are you using? Maybe it's language-dependent, cause I can't think of any way it'd make sense in Python for example. Unless maybe you're talking about a cell in a notebook? (Jupyter) Or maybe you're talking about a code block in Markdown?

@wjandrea RStudio suggests the R programming language

@wjandrea code chunk could also be called a cell or block.
